# Basic SpringMvC controller not working

Tags: java, spring, spring-mvc, jakarta-ee, model-view-controller

I am trying to set up a basic MVC controller project. I have created a servlet and 
couple of jsp pages. I can deploy the project and access the jsp pages.

The problem starts when I try to use the LoginController. The error I am getting is 404 error. Please help.

I have attached a screenshot of my codes and project structure. I gut instinct is the dispatcher servlet is not working the way it suppose to (just a guess).

I have googled and fiddled with the code for the past 5 hours to no avail. This is my first time asking question on S/O [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/tpJwQ.png)so I apologies If this is not in the correct format.

Comment: Which url do you use when you try to access the login controller?

Comment: Your dispatcher servlet mapping looks a bit uncommon. Typical it is mapped to root `<url-pattern>/</url-pattern>`

Comment: http://localhost:8084/springmvcDemo/login

Comment: `localhost:8084/springmvcDemo/login` change to `localhost:8084/springmvcDemo/spring-mvc/login`

Comment: Wow that worked!.....thank you million times. Are you able to explain why that happened?

Comment: Ralph you quickly spotted that, even though Shantaram made it abundantly clear. So thanks you both.

Answer (score 0):

`localhost:8084/springmvcDemo/login`

change to

`localhost:8084/springmvcDemo/spring-mvc/login`

[This link will help you](http://docs.spring.io/spring/docs/current/spring-framework-reference/html/mvc.html)

Comment: @shantaram, could you add in some relevant details from that link? StackOverflow prefers having the actual info in answers, in case the linked content changes or goes away. See https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer.

Comment: Check for Handler mappings