# Basic SpringMVC + Tomcat issue

Tags: java, spring-mvc, tomcat9

[image]I am very new to SpringMVC, and right now I am trying to build a simple application using this tutorial:
http://websystique.com/springmvc/spring-4-mvc-helloworld-tutorial-annotation-javaconfig-full-example/
I have checked
[Basic SpringMvC controller not working](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/39930611/basic-springmvc-controller-not-working) and it does not seem to be my problem, my app is unavailable even when I insert the app name. I use annotation-based config and Tomcat 9.

[image: here is my project structure. The error is eclipse complaining about the issue in pom.xml, while the file itself works fine and the code compiles]
I have three classes:
MainController.java

```
package mvc_webapp.controller;

import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMethod;

@Controller
@RequestMapping("/")
public class MainController {

@RequestMapping(method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String sayHello() {
    return "index";
}

@RequestMapping(value = "/index", method = RequestMethod.GET)
public String indexPage() {
    return "index";
}
}
```

BlogConfiguration.java

```
package mvc_webapp.configuration;

import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.ComponentScan;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.ViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.config.annotation.EnableWebMvc;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.InternalResourceViewResolver;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.view.JstlView;

@Configuration
@EnableWebMvc
@ComponentScan(basePackages = "mvc_webapp")
public class BlogConfiguration {
    @Bean
    public ViewResolver viewResolver() {
        InternalResourceViewResolver viewResolver = new InternalResourceViewResolver();
        viewResolver.setViewClass(JstlView.class);
        viewResolver.setPrefix("WEB-INF/views/");
        viewResolver.setSuffix(".html");
        return viewResolver;
    }
   }
```

BlogInitializer.java

```
package mvc_webapp.configuration;

import javax.servlet.ServletContext;
import javax.servlet.ServletException;
import javax.servlet.ServletRegistration;
import org.springframework.web.WebApplicationInitializer;
import org.springframework.web.context.support.AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext;
import org.springframework.web.servlet.DispatcherServlet;

public class BlogInitializer implements WebApplicationInitializer {

public void onStartup(ServletContext servletContext) throws ServletException {
    AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext ctx = new AnnotationConfigWebApplicationContext();
    ctx.register(BlogConfiguration.class);
    ctx.setServletContext(servletContext);

    ServletRegistration.Dynamic servlet = servletContext.addServlet("dispatcher", new DispatcherServlet(ctx));
    servlet.setLoadOnStartup(1);
    servlet.addMapping("/");
}

}
```

pom.xml

```
<project xmlns="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0"  xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
  xsi:schemaLocation="http://maven.apache.org/POM/4.0.0 http://maven.apache.org/maven-v4_0_0.xsd">
  <modelVersion>4.0.0</modelVersion>
  <groupId>net.atos</groupId>
  <artifactId>mvc_webapp</artifactId>
  <packaging>war</packaging>
  <version>0.0.1-SNAPSHOT</version>
  <name>mvc_webapp Maven Webapp</name>
  <url>http://maven.apache.org</url>
  <dependencies>
    <dependency>
    <groupId>junit</groupId>
  <artifactId>junit</artifactId>
  <version>3.8.1</version>
  <scope>test</scope>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.springframework</groupId>
    <artifactId>spring-webmvc</artifactId>
    <version>5.0.8.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
    <artifactId>javax.servlet-api</artifactId>
    <version>4.0.1</version>
    <scope>provided</scope>
</dependency>       
  </dependencies>
  <build>
    <pluginManagement>
        <plugins>
           <plugin>
                <groupId>org.apache.maven</groupId>
                <artifactId>maven-plugin-api</artifactId>
                <version>3.5.4</version>
                 <configuration>
                    <warSourceDirectory>src/main/webapp</warSourceDirectory>
                    <warName>mvc_webapp</warName>
                    <failOnMissingWebXml>false</failOnMissingWebXml>
             </configuration>
        </plugin>
    </plugins>
</pluginManagement>
<finalName>mvc_webapp</finalName>
```

I more or less understand what these components are, but I cannot detect what exactly is wrong - content of the classes is only slightly different from the tutorial. 
Update:
I added the screenshot with project issues, even though they did not seem to be relevant to me as neither compiler nor build tool issued any errors. Not to mention that pom.xml complains about the value which is not even there.

Comment: Open the problems view in eclipse and share any problems related to this project listed there.

Comment: First fix all the errors in your workspace.

Comment: I added the screenshot, but the messages do not make much sense, and the code seems to be compiling.

Comment: « Make JAR, not WAR. », Josh Long

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So, I ended up abandoning attempts to do it in eclipse, made a WebApp project in Netbeans and with significantly less problems managed to start an annotation-based project there. Thanks everyone for the contributions.

Answer (score 0):

First of all check if the server is running or not try hitting the homepage of apache.

Then check inside tomcat directory inside webapps folder there should be a folder with the name of your application if your application is deployed successfully on server.

Comment: The server is most definitely running, the app is visible in Tomcat Manager, but even in this case I cannot reach it. Most likely there is some problem with my code, I just cannot find where exactly.

Comment: try debugging the app , apply breakpoints at suspicious places and see ,most likely you'll find the problem.

Comment: Have a look at the errors in the `pom.xml` and `web.xml`, you need to address that first.

Comment: well, the tutorial claims that:
web.xml is not needed here, as the configuration is annotation based and <failOnMissingWebXml> is set to FALSE, even though eclipse says otherwise

Comment: Error image wasn't there earlier thats why I suggested to check server.

Comment: Either way, it can't be an answer